# SUN minor code 309 meaning

Tags: java, corba, sun

I've got the following stacktrace:

```
org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 309  completed: No
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.workerThreadThrowableFromRequestWork(ORBUtilSystemException.java:6330)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.workerThreadThrowableFromRequestWork(ORBUtilSystemException.java:6355)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:513)
```

Can you help what this minor code means?

Comment: This is not a standard defined minor code, check the documentation of your CORBA implementation for the meaning of this minor code